# Counting and updating a subset of matrix

Tags: matrix

I have an n by n matrix and would like to count the number of sub-matrices that is equal to a given matrix. Here is my code: DWBCL creates a matrix with elements a1, a2 and c2 in it and DWBCH with b1, b2 and c2.

```
DWBCL[a1_, a2_, c2_, n_] := Module[{M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, Mfinal},
  M0 = IdentityMatrix[n]*c2;
  M1 = ConstantArray[a1, {n, n}];
  M2 = ConstantArray[a2, {n, n}];
  M3 = UpperTriangularize[M1, 1];
  M4 = LowerTriangularize[M2, -1];
  Mfinal = M0 + M3 + M4]
DWBCH[b1_, b2_, c2_, n_] := Reverse[DWBCL[b2, b1, c2, n]]
```

Now, I want to check the total number of sub-matrix $S_a$ in DWBCL or DWBCH where $S_a$ is;

```
Sa = {{b1,c2},{c2,b2}}
```

For example, if I have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b1 & b1 & b1 & b1 & b1 & c2\\
b1 & b1 & b1 & b1 & c2 & b2\\
b1 & b1 & b1 & c2 & b2 & b2\\
b1 & b1 & c2 & b2 & b2 & b2\\
b1 & c2 & b2 & b2 & b2 & b2\\
c2 & b2 & b2 & b2 & b2 & b2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and $ S_a=
\begin{pmatrix}
b1 & c2\\
c2 & b2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

then I want to I want to get 5 because there are 5 such blocks along the anti-diagonal.

After the counting, I want to update one of $S_a$ to $S_b$;

```
Sb = {{c2,c1},{a2,c2}}
```

I tried to use a loop structure to go through every element and use the if statement to check adjacent entries, but I wasn't sure how to do this in *Mathematica*.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: In general the replacement is ill-defined.  In a one-dimensional case, imagine `DWBCL = {1, 1, 1}`, `Sa = {1, 1}`, and `Sb = {1, 2}`.  Should the result be `{1, 2, 2}` or `{1, 1, 2}`?  In your example the ambiguity would be the elements on the diagonal, should they be `c1` or `a1`?

Comment: Thank you! The counting works now! For the replacement, what I want to do is to replace one of Sa to Sb, and I want the position of Sa to be replaced to be chosen according to a random number generator. So using your 1D example, the result will be either {1, 2, 2} or {1, 1, 2} depending on the output of the random number generator. If the result is {1, 1, 2}, then I want to replace Sa once again, obtaining {1, 2, 2}. I am not sure what you mean that diagonal elements should be c1 or a1. Do you mean the diagonal of Sb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll define our matrices.  Using your definitions we can make a matrix `m`:

```
m = DWBCH[b1, b2, c2, 6]
```

`sA` is defined like so:

```
sA = {{b1, c2}, {c2, b2}}
```

(not `Sa`, since Mathematica capitalizes all it's functions we should generally use lowercase variables to avoid collisions.)

We can use `Partition` to split apart the matrix into `sA`-sized subarrays in steps of `1`; then use `Count` to, uh, count how many instances match `sA`:

```
Count[Partition[m, Dimensions[sA], 1], sA, {2}]
(* 5 *)
```